# Select the rows that were just pasted, then sort by column, then clear extra rows

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I am trying to have a macro that does the following 3 steps:

Step 1 - Copy and paste data from a .txt file into excel into the first empty cell

Step 2 - Sort the newly pasted data by the third column (D). There will be hundreds of rows of data above this one that I do not want sorted with it.

Step 3- clear data from all rows not containing numbers which will be the bottom rows, could be 1 row could be 3 rows

```
Sub LASTROW()
Dim rngLast As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RCM")
If .Range("B1").Value = "" Then
Set rngLast = .Range("B1")
Else
Set rngLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End If
rngLast.PasteSpecial

Selection.Sort Key1:=Selection.Cells(1, 3), Header:=xlNo

End With

End Sub
```

Edit: I solved the last step by having a separate macro that did the clearing:

```
Sub ClearHeaders()

    Dim LASTROW As Long
    Dim I As Long

LASTROW = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For I = LASTROW To 2 Step -1
If (Not (IsNumeric(Cells(I, "D")))) Then
 Rows(I).ClearContents
 End If
 Next I

End Sub
```

I'll just have a button that calls up both functions one after the other. Thanks all!

Comment: Hundreds of rows above column (D)?

Comment: Yes, it's going to be an ongoing list. Every time we do the process we will have to paste a new range of data into the sheet. It's right now at row 700 since we began using it on Jan 6 2020

Comment: You mean Hundreds of rows above `rngLast`

Comment: Try the macro recorder for the actions you want to take. Then change the code to work only on the selected region.

Comment: Could you add some more detail to this point `Clear data from all rows not containing numbers which will be the bottom rows, could be 1 row could be 3 rows`?

Comment: There is a row containing headers in the data. Every 40 rows of data in the original file it goes to a new page and adds another row of headers. When I'm copy/pasting it I paste it all in one shot headers included. Then I want to sort the whole thing and remove the headers.

Comment: For the macro recorder here is what I got:
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RCM").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RCM").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D717:D802") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RCM").Sort
        .SetRange Range("B717:S802")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Problem is the range is going to be dynamic every time.

Comment: If you need to add code, please edit your question and add it there: no-one can read that much code posted in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that in the future. In the mean time I've solved all issues should I close the question? How would I do that?

Comment: You can delete it unless you want to post your final code as an answer.